# WPF - How to change content of ContentControl clicking on TreeViewItem?

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, contentcontrol, treeviewitem

I am working on a WPF project and I am facing a problem. I have searched for 2 days  a solution but I have never found anything that could help me...
I have a TreeView with different data types inside and a ContentControl that shows views corresponding to these different data types. I want, when I click on a TreeViewItem that, depending on the data type contained in this TreeViewItem, it changes the view in the ContentControl.
I reached to execute different commands depending on the TreeviewItem selected but it never changes the view... 
Does somebody have an answer or an idea that could help me ?

I use this for my TreeView :

```
<TreeView x:Name="networkTree" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="490" TreeViewItem.Selected="GetHeaderSelectedItem"/>
```

It executes this :

```
public class NetworkConfigViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private IRegionManager regionManager;
    private bool _showRDConf;
    private bool _showNetworkConf;
    private bool _showDeviceInfo;

    public NetworkConfigViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("NetworkConfigInfoRegion", typeof(NetworkConfigInfoView));
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RDConfigurationRegion", typeof(RDConfigurationView));
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("DeviceInfoRegion", typeof(DeviceInfoView));
        ShowNetworkConfCommand = new DelegateCommand(NetworkConf);
        ShowRDConfCommand = new DelegateCommand(RDConf);
        ShowDeviceInfoCommand = new DelegateCommand(DevInfo);
        _showNetworkConf = true;
        _showRDConf = false;
        _showDeviceInfo = false;
    }

    public bool ShowRDConf
    {
        get
        {
            return _showRDConf;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _showRDConf, value);
        }
    }

    public bool ShowNetworkConf
    {
        get
        {
            return _showNetworkConf;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _showNetworkConf, value);
        }
    }

    public bool ShowDeviceInfo
    {
        get
        {
            return _showDeviceInfo;
        }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _showDeviceInfo, value);
        }
    }

    public DelegateCommand ShowNetworkConfCommand { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand ShowRDConfCommand { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand ShowDeviceInfoCommand { get; set; }

    private void NetworkConf()
    {
        ShowRDConf = false;
        ShowDeviceInfo = false;
        ShowNetworkConf = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Commande ShowNetConf executée :\nShowNetworkConf="+ShowNetworkConf.ToString()+"\nShowRDConf="+ShowRDConf.ToString() + "\nShowDeviceInfo=" + ShowDeviceInfo.ToString());
    }

    private void RDConf()
    {
        ShowNetworkConf = false;
        ShowDeviceInfo = false;
        ShowRDConf = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Commande ShowRConf executée :\nShowRDConf="+ShowRDConf.ToString()+"\nShowNetworkConf="+ShowNetworkConf.ToString() + "\nShowRDeviceInfo=" + ShowDeviceInfo.ToString());
    }

    private void DevInfo()
    {
        ShowNetworkConf = false;
        ShowRDConf = false;
        ShowDeviceInfo = true;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Commande ShowDeviceInfo executée :\nShowDeviceInfo=" + ShowDeviceInfo.ToString() + "\nShowNetworkConf=" + ShowNetworkConf.ToString() + "\nShowRDConf=" + ShowRDConf.ToString());
    }

    public void ChangeNetworkView(TreeView tree)
    {
        TreeViewItem tvi = null;
        tvi = tree.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
        if (tvi != null)
        {
            if (tvi.Tag.ToString() == "Network")
            {
                ShowNetworkConfCommand.Execute();
            }
            else if(tvi.Tag.ToString()=="RD")
            {
                ShowRDConfCommand.Execute();
            }
            else if (tvi.Tag.ToString() == "VD")
            {
                ShowDeviceInfoCommand.Execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for my ContentControl :

```
        <ContentControl x:Name="RDView" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowRDConf, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="RDConfigurationRegion"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="NetworkView" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowNetworkConf, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="NetworkConfigInfoRegion"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="DeviceView" x:FieldModifier="public" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowDeviceInfo, Converter={StaticResource Convert}}" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="DeviceInfoRegionq"/>
```

Thank you by advance

Comment: What happens if you remove `Visibility` property from these content controls? I can not see any control/data in your content control.

Comment: I used a BooleanToVisibilityConverter to bind the views

Comment: It's okay but what controls are there inside of content control? Suppose, there is only one content control then are you able to load the view?